# Download image from new Google+ (plus) Photos Application

Tags: android, google-plus, android-contentprovider, google-photos

Recently Google added the Photos app for Google+ (plus) and it shows up when you launch an Intent to choose an image. However, if I select an image from Google+ Photos and try to use it in my application none of my current logic is able to return a usable URI or URL to actually get an image that I can download and manipulate. I'm currently using the "common" methods to try to manipulate the URI that can be found here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I can provide code if needed, but at this point I think it's kind of irrelevant since it works well for everything else except this new app. Any ideas on how to get a usable image?

The URI looks something like the following:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%<a bunch of letters and numbers here>
```

The `MediaColumns.DATA` info always returns null and the `MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` always returns image.jpg no matter what I select from the Google Photos app. If I try to paste everything from https to the end in my browser, nothing comes up. Not sure how to get usable info from this.

Comment: I have the same issue. I need the file contents as well as a file name/title but all I get is `null` ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When receiving the data intent, you should use the contentResolver to get the photos.
Here's what you should do:

```
String url = intent.getData().toString();
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream is = null;
if (url.startsWith("content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content")){
       is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(url));
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}
```

Comment: Duh...I had logic to catch this when it identified the image but I forgot to add an if statement to handle this in my AsyncTask that actually pulled the image down and created a file. Once I did that it now grabbed the image.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? For images, getting a bitmap and saving it to a file would work. How would you handle a video in such a case?

Comment: Is there a way to extract the image name and other metadata using this method?

Comment: For some images `is` is null. Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 1):

I did faced issues selecting images from new Google Photos app. I was able to resolve it by below code.

It works for me, basically what i did is i am  checking if there is any **authority** is there or not in content URI. If it is there i am writing to temporary file and returning path of that temporary image. You can skip compression part while writing to temporary image

```
public static String getImageUrlWithAuthority(Context context, Uri uri) {
    InputStream is = null;
    if (uri.getAuthority() != null) {
        try {
            is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            return writeToTempImageAndGetPathUri(context, bmp).toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Uri writeToTempImageAndGetPathUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

P.S. : I have answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567302/1677824)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use projection in order to get `ImageColumns.DATA` (or `MediaColumns.DATA`):

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    // Projection makes ContentResolver to get needed columns only 
    String[] medData = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, medData, null, null, null);

    // this is how you can simply get Bitmap
    Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), contentURI);

    // After using projection cursor will have needed DATA column
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    final int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 

    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```