# How to pick image for crop from camera or gallery in Android 7.0?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-7.0-nougat

Pick image for crop from gallery and camera it's done for below Android 7.0 but in Android Nought it crashes in camera. I use fileprovider for it but doesn't work.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button mBtn;
private Context context;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_CAMARA = 101, SELECT_PICTURE = 201, CROP_IMAGE = 301;
private Uri outputFileUri;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private Uri selectedImageUri;
private File finalFile = null;
private ImageView imageView;
private PermissionUtil permissionUtil;
Uri fileUri;
File file = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_img);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
    permissionUtil = new PermissionUtil();
    mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    context = this;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    selectImageOption();
}

private void selectImageOption() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Capture Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Capture Photo")) {
                if (permissionUtil.checkMarshMellowPermission()) {
                    if (permissionUtil.verifyPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionUtil.getCameraPermissions()))
                        onClickCamera();
                    else
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionUtil.getCameraPermissions(), SELECT_PICTURE_CAMARA);
                } else
                    onClickCamera();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                if (permissionUtil.checkMarshMellowPermission()) {
                    if (permissionUtil.verifyPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionUtil.getGalleryPermissions()))
                        onClickGallery();
                    else
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionUtil.getGalleryPermissions(), SELECT_PICTURE);
                } else
                    onClickGallery();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            cropImage(selectedImageUri);

        } else if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE) {

            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
            try {
                InputStream ims = new FileInputStream(file);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return;
            }

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_CAMARA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            cropImage1();
        }
    }
}

private void onClickCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
       /* File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {

            Uri photoURI;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
            } else {
                photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            }
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_CAMARA);

        }*/

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
        fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_CAMARA);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_no_camera), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void onClickGallery() {
    List<Intent> targets = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    List<ResolveInfo> candidates = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo candidate : candidates) {
        String packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (!packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.photos") && !packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus") && !packageName.equals("com.android.documentsui")) {
            Intent iWantThis = new Intent();
            iWantThis.setType("image/*");
            iWantThis.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            iWantThis.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            iWantThis.setPackage(packageName);
            targets.add(iWantThis);
        }
    }
    if (targets.size() > 0) {
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targets.remove(0), "Select Picture");
        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targets.toArray(new Parcelable[targets.size()]));
        startActivityForResult(chooser, SELECT_PICTURE);
    } else {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent1.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        mCurrentPhotoPath = String.valueOf(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", image));
    } else {
        mCurrentPhotoPath = String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(image));
    }

    return image;
}

/*private Uri createImageUri(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,timeStamp);
    return contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,cv);
}*/

private void cropImage(Uri selectedImageUri) {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImageUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1.5);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(createCropFile());
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);
}

private void cropImage1() {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1.5);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createCropFile());

    } else
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(createCropFile());

    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);

   /* ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
    outputFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);*/
}

private File createCropFile() {
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    //  path = path + (timeStamp + "1jpg");

    try {
        file = File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".jpg", storageDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
        mCurrentPhotoPath = String.valueOf(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file));
    else*/
    mCurrentPhotoPath = String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(file));
    return file;
}
}
```

> this work in all device but not in >= android 7.0 Nought device

Comment: Can you please provide the logcat and a [mcve]?

Comment: Please do not repost questions. You may edit the previous one to bump it to the front page

Comment: And even if you didn't repost, there is not enough information to help here. The other question is much better

Comment: Refer to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/3209132

Comment: @shweta did u get the answer how to crop the image in android 7 and lesser version of android

Comment: Yes, got the solution.

Comment: I added my solution.

Comment: try this , small and perfect code stackoverflow.com/a/52695444/4997704

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I got the solution.Posting my answer.
>
> **In MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.img_camera)
CircleImageView mImgCamera;

private ChoosePhoto choosePhoto=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.img_camera)
public void onViewClicked() {
    choosePhoto = new ChoosePhoto(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ChoosePhoto.CHOOSE_PHOTO_INTENT) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                choosePhoto.handleGalleryResult(data);
            } else {
                choosePhoto.handleCameraResult(choosePhoto.getCameraUri());
            }
        }else if (requestCode == ChoosePhoto.SELECTED_IMG_CROP) {
            mImgCamera.setImageURI(choosePhoto.getCropImageUrl());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == ChoosePhoto.SELECT_PICTURE_CAMERA) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            choosePhoto.showAlertDialog();
    }
}
}
```

> **ChoosePhoto.java**

```
public class ChoosePhoto {

public static int CHOOSE_PHOTO_INTENT = 101;
public static int SELECTED_IMG_CROP = 102;
public static int SELECT_PICTURE_CAMERA = 103;
public static int currentAndroidDeviceVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

private int ASPECT_X = 1;
private int ASPECT_Y = 1;
private int OUT_PUT_X = 300;
private int OUT_PUT_Y = 300;
private boolean SCALE = true;

private Uri cropPictureUrl, selectedImageUri = null, cameraUrl = null;
private Context mContext;

public ChoosePhoto(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    PermissionUtil permissionUtil = new PermissionUtil();

    if (permissionUtil.checkMarshMellowPermission()) {
        if (permissionUtil.verifyPermissions(mContext, permissionUtil.getCameraPermissions()) && permissionUtil.verifyPermissions(mContext, permissionUtil.getGalleryPermissions()))
            showAlertDialog();
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, permissionUtil.getCameraPermissions(), SELECT_PICTURE_CAMERA);
        }
    } else {
        showAlertDialog();
    }
}

public void showAlertDialog() {
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

    cameraUrl = FileUtil.getInstance(mContext).createImageUri();
    //Create any other intents you want
    final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraUrl);


    //Add them to an intent array
    Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{cameraIntent};

    //Create a choose from your first intent then pass in the intent array
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, mContext.getString(R.string.choose_photo_title));
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);

    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CHOOSE_PHOTO_INTENT);
}

// Change this method(edited)
public void handleGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    try {
        cropPictureUrl = Uri.fromFile(FileUtil.getInstance(mContext)
                .createImageTempFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));
        String realPathFromURI = FileUtil.getRealPathFromURI(mContext, data.getData());
        File file = new File(realPathFromURI == null ? getImageUrlWithAuthority(mContext, data.getData()) : realPathFromURI);
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (currentAndroidDeviceVersion > 23) {
                cropImage(FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file), cropPictureUrl);
                
            } else {
                cropImage(Uri.fromFile(file), cropPictureUrl);
            }

        } else {
            cropImage(data.getData(), cropPictureUrl);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getImageUrlWithAuthority(Context context, Uri uri) {
    InputStream is = null;
    if (uri.getAuthority() != null) {
        try {
            is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            return writeToTempImageAndGetPathUri(context, bmp).toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Uri writeToTempImageAndGetPathUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}


public void handleCameraResult(Uri cameraPictureUrl) {
    try {
        cropPictureUrl = Uri.fromFile(FileUtil.getInstance(mContext)
                .createImageTempFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));

        cropImage(cameraPictureUrl, cropPictureUrl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public Uri getCameraUri() {
    return cameraUrl;
}

public Uri getCropImageUrl() {
    return selectedImageUri;
}

private void cropImage(final Uri sourceImage, Uri destinationImage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        //Utils.showToast(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.error_cant_select_cropping_app));
        selectedImageUri = sourceImage;
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, sourceImage);
        ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, SELECTED_IMG_CROP);
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setDataAndType(sourceImage, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", ASPECT_X);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", ASPECT_Y);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", OUT_PUT_Y);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", OUT_PUT_X);
        intent.putExtra("scale", SCALE);

        //intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, destinationImage);
        selectedImageUri = destinationImage;
        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, SELECTED_IMG_CROP);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, list.toArray(new Parcelable[list.size()]));
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, SELECTED_IMG_CROP);
        }
    }
}
}
```

> **FileUtil.java**

```
public class FileUtil {
private static FileUtil sSingleton;
private Context context;

private FileUtil(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

/**
 * Gets instance.
 *
 * @param ctx the ctx
 * @return the instance
 */
public static FileUtil getInstance(Context ctx) {
    if (sSingleton == null) {
        synchronized (FileUtil.class) {
            sSingleton = new FileUtil(ctx);
        }
    }
    return sSingleton;
}

public Uri createImageUri() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, timeStamp);
    return contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
}

/**
 * Create image temp file file.
 *
 * @param filePathDir the file path dir
 * @return the file
 * @throws IOException the io exception
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public File createImageTempFile(File filePathDir) throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    return File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            filePathDir      /* directory */
    );
}

public static  String getUploadFileName() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
    Date date = new Date();
    return String.format("profile_%s.png", sdf.format(date));
}

 //add this code(edited)
 //get Path
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
  public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    } else
        return getRealPathFromURIDB(uri);

    return null;
}

/**
 * Gets real path from uri.
 *
 * @param contentUri the content uri
 * @return the real path from uri
 */
private static String getRealPathFromURIDB(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        String realPath = cursor.getString(index);
        cursor.close();
        return realPath;
    }
}

/**
 * Gets data column.
 *
 * @param uri           the uri
 * @param selection     the selection
 * @param selectionArgs the selection args
 * @return the data column
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Is external storage document boolean.
 *
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * Is downloads document boolean.
 *
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * Is media document boolean.
 *
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * Is google photos uri boolean.
 *
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
  }
```

> PermissionUtil.java

```
public class PermissionUtil {
      private String[] galleryPermissions = {
          "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
          "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      };

private String[] cameraPermissions = {
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
};

public String[] getGalleryPermissions(){
    return galleryPermissions;
}

public String[] getCameraPermissions() {
    return cameraPermissions;
}

public boolean verifyPermissions(Context context, String[] grantResults) {
    for (String result : grantResults) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, result) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean checkMarshMellowPermission(){
    return(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}

public static void showPermissionDialog(Context mContext,String msg){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.DatePicker);
    builder.setTitle("Need Permission");
    builder.setMessage(msg);
    builder.setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.invitation_yes), (dialogInterface, i) -> {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mContext.getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        (mContext).startActivity(intent);
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.invitation_del_no), (dialogInterface, i) -> {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

}

> provide_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: you did a great job but can you tell me how can i remove crop section and get full image

Comment: @Shweta  could you please post here `PermissionUtil` file

Comment: yea sure.let me add.

Comment: @pb123 PermissionUtil class added.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan could you please share your xml file with paths? Or if you have - github page

Comment: @Alex.Marinovskiy : I added XML file with path.Check it.

Comment: need some help. i am getting "java.lang.SecurityException: UID does not have permission to content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider" when i try crop image that is picked from device. works everything fine when i capture new image.

Comment: @ZeeshanGhazanfar : It's because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572261/using-data-from-context-providers-or-requesting-google-photos-read-permission

Comment: @ZeeshanGhazanfar : I also face same issue but I have solution let me edit my answer

Comment: @ZeeshanGhazanfar : I updated my answer.There were 2 changes in 2 files where I put comment "edited".

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I have followed the same procedure, I am getting only for the first time again when user tries second time I m getting this exception
`resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20180406_123024_471987481.jpg`

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal : I also got same error for android 7 and after that I added this answer. Now, I also have to check for Android 8.0. Let you know whenever I solved issue.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan this code is not working in redmi mobile it is directly going to else part and I am getting resultcode 0

The following code not working for redmi

` if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
}`

Comment: I have followed the same code its working with android N with 7.1.1(other mobiles working)  but mine is redmi with same version and same OS it it not working for me.
I am getting below exception

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/13423 from pid=23554, uid=10121 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`

Answer (score 19):

I just solve this problem on Nexus6p android N,you need grant permission to uri  so the system camera can access the file wait crop temporarily,because of StrictMode Android N has do not support pass a file:Uri in an Intent extra anymore see [Scheme Ban in N Developer Preview](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html),we use `FileProvider` instead.here is my source code:

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="dreamgo.corp.provider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

`filepaths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="images" path="."/>
</paths>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "dreamgo.corp.provider", file);
//grant uri with essential permission the first arg is the The packagename you would like to allow to access the Uri.
context.grantUriPermission("com.android.camera",photoURI,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "image/*");

//you must setup two line below
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
//you must setup this
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: can you please give suggestion how I store image in ImageView after cropping(when requestCode == CROP_IMAGE).Because after I crop image It crash in Android Nought In Camera.

Comment: before Android N I use `Bitmap bitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");` but this not work on Android N.I create a temp file for Camera and get uri from this temp file after user take a picture by camera,cut(crop) the tempfile   with tempfile uri.system will change the tempfile after user cut it.I will post all  code in another answer under this question.

Comment: what is the file name and context here

Comment: sorry,couldn‘t help you about this.

Answer (score 2):

I have two source for crop,one is gallery and the other one is camera

the method gallery:

```
//take a photo from gallery
public void gallery() {
    //set UUID to filename
    String PHOTO_FILE_NAME = UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg";
    Utils.putValue(this, Constants.UserPortraitFilePath,PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST_GALLERY);
}
```

the method camera:

```
    //take a photo from camera
public void camera() {
    //check sdcard is usable or not
    if (Utils.hasSdcard()) {
        //set UUID to filename
        String PHOTO_FILE_NAME = UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg";
        Utils.putValue(this,Constants.UserPortraitFilePath,PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        //set file location to DreamGo/Image
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(path, "DreamGo/Image");
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        //Android N need use FileProvider get file 
        //uri because StrictMode System
        //getUriForFile(content,provider author,file)
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "dream.go.provider",
                new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), PHOTO_FILE_NAME));
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }else {
        showToast("no storage device");
    }
}
```

the crop method:

```
    //Android N crop image
public void crop(Uri uri) {
    context.grantUriPermission("com.android.camera",uri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    //Android N need set permission to uri otherwise system camera don't has permission to access file wait crop
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //The proportion of the crop box is 1:1
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //Crop the output image size
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 800);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 800);
    //image type
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "JPEG");
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
    //true - don't return uri |  false - return uri
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CUT);
}
```

the onActivityResult method :

```
private static final int PHOTO_REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;//camera
private static final int PHOTO_REQUEST_GALLERY = 1;//gallery
private static final int PHOTO_REQUEST_CUT = 2;//image crop
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String PHOTO_FILE_NAME = Utils.getValue(this, Constants.UserPortraitFilePath);
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(path, "DreamGo/Image");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case PHOTO_REQUEST_GALLERY:
            if (data != null){
                //file from gallery
                File sourceFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));
                //blank file DreamGo/Image/uuid.jpg
                File destFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
                Log.e("photo",data.getData().getPath());
                try {
                    //copy file from gallery to DreamGo/Image/uuid.jpg
                    // otherwise crop method can't cut image without write permission
                    copyFile(sourceFile,destFile);
                    //Android N need use FileProvider to get file uri
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "dream.go.provider", destFile);
                    //cut image
                    crop(photoURI);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
        case PHOTO_REQUEST_CAMERA:
            //whether sdcard is usable has been checked before use camera
            File tempFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "dream.go.provider", tempFile);
            crop(photoURI);
            break;
        case PHOTO_REQUEST_CUT:
            try {
                if(data!=null) {
                    file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
                    icon.loadImage("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }else {
                    showToast("a error happened when cut picture");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

the realted code:

```
//copy sourceFile to destFile
public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }
}

//file uri to real location in filesystem
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
}

public static final String getValue(Context context, String key) {
    return getSharedPreference(context).getString(key, "");
}
public static final boolean putValue(Context context, String key,
                                     String value) {
    value = value == null ? "" : value;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(context).edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    boolean result = editor.commit();
    if (!result) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "dream.go.provider", destFile); in these line i m getting file not found exception

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this in Manifest.xml??

```
<application
        ........
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

this has to be there in your manifest.. for effect in the naugut android 7.0.

Again you need to add **provider_paths.xml** file in **xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en
Go with this tutorial

Comment: I refered this tutorial and from this tutorial I got this solution(Provider).From this tutorial I done till crop with camare but after cropping it crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + Configs.FILE_PROVIDER_NAME, inFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outFile));
```

You should notice that the uri for EXTRA_OUTPUT should not be modified by FileProvider.
And your paths.xml should like this

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_sd" path="."/>
<external-files-path name="external_app" path="."/>
<files-path name="files" path="."/>
<cache-path name="cache" path="."/>
```

Because you create crop file under getExternalFilesDir. So `<external-files-path>` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works for me. I've tested with Gallery, Google drive, Photos etc.

Sample is in `Kotlin` language.

**ImagePickUtils.kt**

```
fun getImageUri(context: Context, contentURI: String): Uri {
    var conUri = Uri.parse(contentURI)
    var filePath = ""
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, conUri)) {
        val wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(conUri)

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        val id = wholeID.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()[1]

        val column = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

        // where id is equal to
        val sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?"

        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, arrayOf(id), null) ?: return conUri

        val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0])

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        }
        cursor.close()

        if (filePath.isNotEmpty()) {
            filePath = filePath.replace(" ".toRegex(), "%20")
            conUri = Uri.parse("file://$filePath")
        }
    }
    return conUri
}
```

**onActivityResult** of Activity / Fragment:

```
if (data != null) {
    val imagePath: Uri
    if (data.data != null) {
           val mImageUri = data.data
           imagePath = getImageUri(this@HomeActivity, mImageUri.toString())
           Log.i(TAG+" Image actual path", imagePath.toString())
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
Uri contentUri = imageUri;
pickImageIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
pickImageIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, RESULT_CROP);
```

Comment: You should provide additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ this code solves the problem. That would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43231334/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me like charm for Marshmallow as well as for 7.1.2 (Naugat)

1. To pick image from camera, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/1911652) follow these steps from [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) blog:

Write code as described in this step for both, Marshmallow as well as for 7.1.2 (Naugat)

2. To crop the image, if you want to use intent `com.android.camera.action.CROP` (which is actually not recommanded but still many developer use), then you can call these methods with URI in old style. i.e. `Uri.fromFile(file)`

`cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");`

and

`cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));`

along with other methods (please search how to call intent `com.android.camera.action.CROP`)

And, finally *before* calling `startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_ACTIVITY_CODE)`
make sure to write this this...

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24)
        {
            try
            {
                Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                m.invoke(null);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

That's it! I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this [library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) which will be helpful to clean your project from boilerplate code for image pick and crop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

This method of cropping was not working in google photos and I realized that it is not supported by all devices and galleries, So I created my own method of cropping. There are two small problems that I still face, if someone could help me in solving that too. Otherwise this class is working all fine.

Drawable:

crop_rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:color="@color/white"
    android:width="3dp"
    android:dashGap="10dp"
    android:dashWidth="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Layout:
activity_crop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginVertical="70dp">

    <FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/full_screen_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:tint="#aa111111" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/crop_area"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/crop_rectangle"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/close_image_viewer"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/save_image"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/white" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

CropActivity.kt

```
class CropActivity : Activity() {

private lateinit var closeBt: ImageView
private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
private lateinit var cropArea: ImageView
private lateinit var saveImage: ImageView

private var mScaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector? = null
private var mGestureListener: GestureDetector? = null
var mScaleFactor = 1.0f
var xPos = 0.0f
var yPos = 0.0f
val minZoom = 0.2f
val maxZoom = 1.0f

lateinit var bmp: Bitmap

var oldE2X: Float = 0f
var oldE2Y: Float = 0f
var height: Int = 0
var width: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop)
    closeBt = findViewById(R.id.close_image_viewer)
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.full_screen_image_view)
    cropArea = findViewById(R.id.crop_area)
    saveImage = findViewById(R.id.save_image)

    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels

    val filepath = intent.getStringExtra(AppConsts.IMAGE_STRING)
    try {
        //val file = File(filepath!!)
        bmp = getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath), width)!!
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)

        val layoutParams = cropArea.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        val ratio = if (intent.hasExtra(AppConsts.IMAGE_RATIO))
            intent.getStringExtra(AppConsts.IMAGE_RATIO)
        else
            "H,1:1"

        layoutParams.dimensionRatio = ratio

        val imageWidth = bmp.width
        val imageHeight = bmp.height
        val bitmapRatio: Float = imageWidth.toFloat() / imageHeight.toFloat()

        cropArea.layoutParams = layoutParams

        if (bitmapRatio <= 1f) {
            cropArea.layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        } else {
            cropArea.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        finish()
    }

    xPos = cropArea.x
    yPos = cropArea.y
    mScaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, ScaleListener())
    mGestureListener = GestureDetector(this, GestureListener())

    saveImage.setOnClickListener {
        saveImage()
    }

}

private fun saveImage() {
    val loc = IntArray(2)
    cropArea.getLocationOnScreen(loc)

    val locImage = IntArray(2)
    imageView.getLocationOnScreen(locImage)

    var bx = loc[0] - locImage[0]
    var by = loc[1] - locImage[1]
    val bWidth = (cropArea.width * mScaleFactor).toInt()
    val bHeight = (cropArea.height * mScaleFactor).toInt()

    if (bx + bWidth > bmp.width)
        bx = getCorrectBx(bx, bWidth)

    if (bx < 0)
        bx = 0

    if (by + bHeight > bmp.height)
        by = getCorrectYx(by, bHeight)

    if (by < 0)
        by = 0

    val croppedBmp: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bmp,
        bx,
        by,
        bWidth,
        bHeight
    )

    val dir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.absolutePath
    val file = File(dir!!)
    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs()

    val path = "$dir/cameraResult.png"
    val image = File(path)
    if (!image.exists())
        image.createNewFile()

    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    croppedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val byteArray: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    image.writeBytes(byteArray)

    val data = Intent()
    data.putExtra(AppConsts.FILE_URI, Uri.fromFile(image).toString())
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data)
    finish()
    //imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp)
}

private fun getCorrectBx(bx: Int, bWidth: Int): Int {
    val newbx = bx - (bmp.width - (bx + bWidth) + 10)
    return if (newbx + bWidth > bmp.width)
        getCorrectBx(newbx, bWidth)
    else
        newbx
}

private fun getCorrectYx(by: Int, bHeight: Int): Int {
    val newby = by - (bmp.height - (by + bHeight) + 10)
    return if (newby + bHeight > bmp.height)
        getCorrectBx(newby, bHeight)
    else
        newby
}

override fun onTouchEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    mScaleGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    mGestureListener!!.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    return true
}

inner class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    override fun onScale(scaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.scaleFactor
        mScaleFactor = minZoom.coerceAtLeast(mScaleFactor.coerceAtMost(maxZoom))
        cropArea.scaleX = mScaleFactor
        cropArea.scaleY = mScaleFactor
        val loc = IntArray(2)
        cropArea.getLocationOnScreen(loc)
        return true
    }
}

inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onScroll(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent?,
        distanceX: Float,
        distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val oldCropLoc = IntArray(2)
        cropArea.getLocationOnScreen(oldCropLoc)

        val locImage = IntArray(2)
        imageView.getLocationOnScreen(locImage)

        if (oldE2X - e2!!.x > 100f || oldE2X - e2.x < -100f) {
            oldE2X = e2.x
            return true
        }

        if (oldE2Y - e2.y > 100f || oldE2Y - e2.y < -100f) {
            oldE2Y = e2.y
            return true
        }

        when {
            oldCropLoc[0] < locImage[0] + 10f && (oldE2X - e2.x) > 0f -> {
                //cropArea.translationX = (-oldCropLoc[0]).toFloat()
                //cropArea.left = imageView.left + 1
                oldE2X = width.toFloat()
            }

            (oldCropLoc[0] + cropArea.width * mScaleFactor) + 10f > locImage[0] + imageView.width &&
                    (oldE2X - e2.x) < 0f -> {
                //cropArea.right = imageView.right - 1
                oldE2X = 0f
            }

            else -> {
                xPos += distanceX
                cropArea.translationX = -xPos
            }
        }

        when {
            oldCropLoc[1] < locImage[1] + 10f && (oldE2Y - e2!!.y) > 0f -> {
                //cropArea.top = imageView.top + 1
                oldE2Y = height.toFloat()
            }

            (oldCropLoc[1] + cropArea.height * mScaleFactor) + 10f > locImage[1] + imageView.height &&
                    (oldE2Y - e2.y) < 0f -> {
                oldE2Y = 0f
                //cropArea.bottom = imageView.bottom - 1
            }

            else -> {
                yPos += distanceY
                cropArea.translationY = -yPos
            }
        }
        oldE2X = e2.x
        oldE2Y = e2.y
        return true
    }
}

private fun highlightPixels(myBitmap: Bitmap/*, a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int*/){
    val pixels = IntArray(myBitmap.height * myBitmap.width)
    myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.width, 0, 0, myBitmap.width, myBitmap.height)
    for (i in 0 until myBitmap.width * 5) pixels[i] = Color.BLUE
    myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.width, 0, 0, myBitmap.width, myBitmap.height)
}

private fun getResizedBitmap(image: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): Bitmap? {
    var width = image.width
    var height = image.height
    val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
    width = maxSize
    height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
}
}
```

How to use:

From your image selection activity assuming you are getting proper Uri from image chooser. pass that Uri to the following function:

```
private fun openCropActivity(contentUri: Uri) {
    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
        contentResolver, contentUri
    )

    val dir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.absolutePath
    val file = File(dir!!)
    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs()

    val path = "$dir/cameraResult.png"
    val image = File(path)
    if (!image.exists())
        image.createNewFile()

    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val byteArray: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    image.writeBytes(byteArray)

    val cropIntent = Intent(this, CropActivity::class.java)
    cropIntent.putExtra(AppConsts.IMAGE_STRING, path)
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP)
}
```

and in your activity result get the uri of cropped image as following

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    val uri: Uri? = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra(AppConsts.FILE_URI))
}
```

Assign the constants as per your will.

The two problems that I am facing is that.

1. The aspect ratio is still fix that you get from the intent or 1:1 if not. you cannot change the aspect ratio using gestures or aanything
2. I wanted to highlight the uncropped/cropped area so that these can be distinguished easily if the bg is white.