# Camera stops, bitmap is null

Tags: android, android-camera, onactivityresult

New on android, i have one button to open gallery select a picture and display it into an imageview, which works properly, and another button to open the camera using Intent, i can open the camera take a picture but after clicking save image the app crashes. The image taken is saved in the correct folder. and when debbugin the app the error thrown its on this line:

```
filePath = data.getData();
```

and bitmap shows it as null. 
I have added the permissions and i have read many post about this but still can't figure it out what is the problem. Any help is appreciated.
Here's the code.

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){
        Toast.makeText(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), "si hay foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

filePath = data.getData();

try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            areaLeyendaImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            areaFotoCargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textoimagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            area_cerrarIagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cerrarImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            areaLeyendaImagen.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            areaLeyendaImagen.requestFocus();
            areaLeyendaImagen.setFocusable(true);
            buttonChoose.setError(null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            areaLeyendaImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            areaFotoCargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textoimagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            area_cerrarIagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cerrarImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonChoose.setError(null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
a E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
08-13 23:50:38.243 27745-27745/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta 
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = 
com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@39e18a4
08-13 23:50:51.483 27745-27745/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 27745
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=66849, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5004)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5047)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC.onActivityResult(TerminosYC.java:463)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5000)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5047) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

UPDATE:

Once the picture is attached on the imageview, and i click on a button to send the picture to store it in a db, i get this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 15254
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC.getPath(TerminosYC.java:549)
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC$1.onClick(TerminosYC.java:352)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Are you testing it in a Samsung device by chance?

Comment: Yes it's a samsung device. @Enzokie

Comment: It's a bug in Samsung ;) Therefore assume that getData will be null at some point.

Comment: I've tested it before using Intent but saving the picture on the phone memory and it work property, but had to change that because it didn't work on nougat devices. @Enzokie

Comment: If you remember before you open the Camera Intent you are actually providing a `Uri` in that case hold that `Uri` instance until you save your image. Do not rely on `getData` because it has its own issue. Do not also forget to retain its instance because Samsung is notorious in killing background Activities base on my experience.

Comment: All right, thanks for the information, i will check that out.

Comment: this not perfect solution but check this once may you get your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44964221/6021469

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
     MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CLICK_RESULT);
```

and on `onActivityResult`

```
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_CLICK_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = null;
        try {
            photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your codes do. But, the log says that: the application has been crashed because of **null pointer exception**.

Check the `main` method of `ZygoteInit.java` class . At `1120` line, you try to get something from null instance.

You should fix this.

Comment: Thanks i will check that, and update information about the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here ,, intead of this

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
```

change like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: Sorry, what would it be ImagePicker, i got the 'cannot resolve symbol' on this

Comment: did you add this line ??? try adding this line in Intent 
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
and try with your own code  
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);

Comment: I already add that line, used  bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentRe‌​solver(), filePath); and the app doesn't crash after saving saving the picture, but it crashes in another part of my code. let me show you to see if you can help me please

Comment: this is the line cursor.moveToFirst();

Answer (score 0):

You can get Bitmap When REQUEST_CAMERA

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

You can get Bitmap When PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST from gallery

```
   Uri uri = data.getData();
  try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mcontext.getContentResolver(), uri);
                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
     } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
     }
```