# Unable to pick the image from the gallery from android 7.1 and above devices

Tags: android

I am trying to pick the image from the gallery and it is working fine in below android 7.1 but from android 7.1 it is not working for me. How to fix the same. 
This the code which I tried :

```
public void LaunchGalleryView() {
        mFileUri = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
    }
```

This is the code in onActivityResult():

```
 case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:
                if (data == null) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                File file = new File(picturePath);
                mFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                performCrop();
                break;
```

How to fix the same please help me.

This is the error log:

> 12-28 05:13:30.085 13533-13533/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      Process: com.welldoc.platform.android.cyan, PID: 13533
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey:/local%3Aefc38517-5fd9-4b57-afbf-6329e508fb66/ORIGINAL/NONE/1646850308
>   flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list
>   U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253Aefc38517-5fd9-4b57-afbf-6329e508fb66/ORIGINAL/NONE/1646850308}
>   }} to activity
>   {com.welldoc.platform.android.cyan/com.welldoc.platform.android.ui.profile.ProfileDetailsEditActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4324)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at java.io.File.(File.java:282)
>                                                          at com.welldoc.platform.android.ui.profile.ProfileDetailsEditActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileDetailsEditActivity.java:1059)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: What is the error ? have a look into [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313752/how-to-pick-image-for-crop-from-camera-or-gallery-in-android-7-0).

Comment: Can your share error log?

Comment: check permissions also

Comment: cursor.getString()method is giving null it means I am getting picturepath as null

Comment: Yes I have checked the permission at runtime also

Comment: I have edited the question and added the error log please have a look and help me out

Comment: Any solution???

Answer (score 0):

1.
Compare the picture path with other mobiles picture selected path, sometimes the path format may vary, so you can get null.

Comment: so, how we can set the format differently based upon the version? currently for the devices above 7.1 I am getting piicturepath null I am not getting any picturepath itself.

Comment: are you compared the selected path? do you find any differences between them?

Comment: ye I got the difference. for few devices path starts with file:/// and for few devices path starts with content:///. the device whose path has been started with file:/// is crashing

Comment: refer this link may be useful for you:
http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` requires you to create custom `FileProvider` and define it in app's manifest:

> authority  String: The authority of a FileProvider defined in a  element in your app's manifest.

If you just want to get `Uri` for your file, you can use the next code:

```
Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: I already define the custom provider in my manifest                     <providerthis is the same
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

Comment: Please, provide `@xml/provider_paths` too

Comment: <path xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</path>

Comment: Can you please, also provide `image name`? Because I can't reproduce it

Comment: image name ? I am not getting what you are asking for can you please tell me which image name you want please

Comment: How image which you are picking named in your storage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162088/discussion-between-alexey-and-shree).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to pick the image from the gallery and it is working fine in below android 7.1

Only on the devices that you tried, for the scenarios that you tried. It will fail on many other devices, and for other scenarios:

- There is no requirement for `ACTION_PICK` to return a `Uri` from the `MediaStore`
- There is no requirement for the `MediaStore` to give you a path
- There is no requirement for the `MediaStore` to give you a path that you can read from, let alone write to

> This is the code in onActivityResult():

You already have a `Uri`. You do not need `FileProvider` for that. You do not need to query the `MediaStore` for that. `selectedImage` is the `Uri`. So, use that with your preferred [image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), and have that library save its results to some file that you control.

If, for some reason, you need a file at the outset:

- Call `getContentResolver()` to get a `ContentResolver`
- Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in `selectedImage`, to get an `InputStream` on that content
- Create a `FileOutputStream` on a file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Copy the data from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`
- Use the resulting file

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- you have to remove this line from your code just add this `startActivityForResult(intent,1);`
- I think that you are passing **wrong intent** which tends not to open `gallery` it open `DocumentProvider`
- put this in your `OnActivityResult`

  ```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
          try {
              uri = null;
              uri = data.getData();
              Bitmap bmp = null;
              file_galleryimagepath = null;
              bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

              File f = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
              if (f.exists())
                  f.delete();
              f.createNewFile();
              Bitmap bitmap = bmp;
              ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
              byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
              fos.write(bitmapdata);
              fos.flush();
              fos.close();
              file_galleryimagepath = f;
              Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_galleryimagepath.toString());
              iv_userImage.setImageBitmap(map);

          }catch (Exception e){
              Log.e("204","HFP>>>"+e+"<<catch");
          }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

---

- when you try to get `file path` from `DocumentProvider' its result becomes`crash` so you've to pass intent like this.