# Accessed denied when using Uri retrieved from OnActivityResult using Glide library

Tags: android, android-glide

I've already declared READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE under the Android Manifest using both the tag uses-permission and uses-permission-sdk-23. I've also requested from the user READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. I've also, used the flag FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            photoPickerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            if (photoPickerIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
            }
```

This is how I'm requesting a photo from the user to be retrieved in onActivityResult. I'm also using the glide library to retrieve the photo from the user.

`requestMgr.load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(imageView);`

That's what's written after I check if the intent I get back from onActivityResult is null.

```
 if(intent != null){
     Uri uri = intent.getData();
     requestMgr.load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(imageView);
 } else {
     displayImageStorageErrorMessage();
     loadProfileImage();
}
```

loadProfileImage() is just a fallback in case anything happens when I try to load the image. Glide.with() is written before the intent is checked because I also use it for when the user wants to take a selfie.

However, the imageView does not display the image that was selected by the user. The result, after I attach a requestlistener to Glide is the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:315)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:220)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1498)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:20)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:11)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailedInternal(SourceGenerator.java:160)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:83)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:167)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:408)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailedInternal(SourceGenerator.java:160)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator$1.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:83)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:167)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:49)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

Is there something I'm missing about permissions that I haven't done yet?

Comment: Need to use `FileProvider` check [How to pick image for crop from camera or gallery in Android 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313752/how-to-pick-image-for-crop-from-camera-or-gallery-in-android-7-0)

Comment: `photoPickerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`. Remove that line. It makes no sense. You cannot grant anything here.

Comment: `requestMgr.load(new File(uri.getPath())).into(imageView);`. You should not use the File class on that uri. You should use code like `requestMgr.load(uri).into(imageView);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1: `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type

Problem #2: `ACTION_PICK` does use a `Uri` indicating the collection that you are picking from, and you are not providing one

Problem #3: `ACTION_PICK` is likely to return a `content` `Uri` via `onActivityResult()`, not something with a filesystem path

Problem #4: `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` is pointless, as you are not supplying a `content` `Uri` to another app, let alone one for which you have read permission that you could grant

To address these, replace your first code snippet with something like:

```
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

        if (photoPickerIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
        }
```

Replace your second code snippet with something like:

```
if(intent != null){
     Uri uri = intent.getData();
     requestMgr.load(uri).into(imageView);
 } else {
     displayImageStorageErrorMessage();
     loadProfileImage();
}
```

Comment: I'm a moron. I had a method in onStart reset the imageview I was using. You were right though. Thank you!