# Download image from new Google+ (plus) Photos Of Gallery with Image Extension

Tags: android, google-plus

In new android version, they have added gplus photo section in gallery.

In my application, i have incorporated the logic of selecting image from it and display to the user using below link of stackoverflow:

[Download image from new Google+ (plus) Photos Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805966/download-image-from-new-google-plus-photos-application)

However, i also need image extension as we are sending image raw data with extension of selected picture to the API. gplus returns the image path like this

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%<a bunch of letters and numbers here>
```

So, how can i get extension of that image also from gplus?? Any idea??

**I AM SUCCESSFULLY GETTING BITMAP FROM ABOVE URI. I JUST NEED EXTENSION OF THAT IMAGE NOW.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ContentResolver.getType(uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29):

```
Uri uri = // your content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content URI
String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
// mimeType will be image/png, image/jpeg, etc.
```

Comment: Many many thanks @ianhanniballake. let me try it and update you soon. :)