# How to get path from cursor id in android

Tags: android, path, android-cursor

Now i am going on with the selection of multiple **image and video** i went through

https://github.com/voidberg/DmxMediaPicker which is exactly what i need but here i get only type,id.

Below code which is used to get the id and type from here how can i get the path of particular image or video which is selected.

```
 if (type == 0) {
idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED);
}

else {
idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
}
```

Tried a lot to **customize** by below but no use:

int **id** =cur.getInt(idColumn);

I tried to get the path of particular **image or video** from **id** but no change.

If anyone have idea about this please help to solve this issue.

Comment: can you put your whole code instead of this snippet?

Comment: please see the above github link

Answer (score 0):

Be careful here. You cannot assume that a media item *necessarily* corresponds to a file on the device. For example, you could be picking a Google+ image or video.

In those cases, the content of the `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` will be empty.

The correct way to do this is not to think about files, but rather about Uris and streams. In particular, from a media item's `Uri`, you can obtain an `InputStream` with its content by using a [`ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

Take a look at this example (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27586116/82788), for images):

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(mediaUri.getScheme())) {
    inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mediaUri);
} else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals(mediaUri.getScheme())) {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(mediaUri.getPath());
}

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```