# How to pick those photo stored in cloud from Google Photos?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I know how to pick photo from gallery and it always work.

The code to pick photo from gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_GALLERY);
```

And code to handle result in `onActivityResult()`:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
}, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) return false;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String path = cursor.getString(0);
    if (path != null) {
           startPhotoEdit(new File(path), output, requestCode);
           cursor.close();
           return true;
    }
}
cursor.close();
```

This time I pick them from Google Photos and the photo is still stored in cloud and not downloaded to local yet. After I pick one and it starts downloading like that:

[photo_downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcaRi.jpg)

When the download task finished and return to my application, the `_data` column in cursor which always contains photo path is null.

Can someone help me, please.

Comment: This code works for Google photos https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193985/1448357

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks! Your answer is similar to what I want. But I prefer this more effective. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/32326558/8404007](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32326558/8404007)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find that when photo from cloud is picked, its `Uri` is different. Like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/1/1/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253A131b7978-cc48-4206-8561-d18f99421551/ORIGINAL/NONE/2134743478
```

It contains `mediakey` instead of `content` in normal `Uri`.

So, this might be helpful:

`getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`