# Video picking is returning an unusual content uri which fails to provide id suitable for loading thumbnail

Tags: android

```
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 2346;

public void chooseVideo(View view) {
    Intent videoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    videoPickerIntent.setType("video/*");
    startActivityForResult(videoPickerIntent, SELECT_VIDEO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri video = data.getData();
    }
}
```

The `uriString` of `video` is `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F141694/ACTUAL/1441715445`

Path: `/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F141694/ACTUAL/1441715445`

`ContentUris.parseId(video)` gives `1441715445` where as I believe I'm looking to get `141694`

It's kind of double encoded it seems with this `/ACTUAL/...` on the end confusing matters.

Is the fault in my understanding or code or with the gallery activity?

Related, but no clean solution given: [Choosing photo using new Google Photos app is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527045/choosing-photo-using-new-google-photos-app-is-broken)

## What I need the id for:

I want the `id` just so I can get the thumbnail:

```
long id = ContentUris.parseId(video);
Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), id,
                  MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

Comment: "I believe I'm looking to get 141694" -- why? What exactly are you expecting to be able to do with that number? There is no requirement for a `Uri` to have any sort of number that you can use for any particular purpose.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want the `id`, so I can get thumbnail: `Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);`

Comment: There is no requirement that the video returned by `ACTION_PICK` have a thumbnail in the `MediaStore`. `ACTION_PICK` can be satisfied by any number of activities from any number of apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK, but when it does have a thumb I'd like to display it. What would you do, ignore this route and generate a new thumb perhaps?

Comment: That would be the safest approach.

Comment: @CommonsWare With [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)?

Comment: Ummm... you can try that. Just realized that it takes a "file path", which is disconcerting, as it may or may not be able to handle a `content://` "path". But that's what I was thinking of. Android, on the whole, wants you to use `Uri` abstractions, then seems to want file paths everywhere. :-(

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah I just hit that road block. Erm, maybe I can get a shot from a `MediaPlayer` instance

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution I feel, and you must be prepared for it to return an invalid `id` as CommonsWare says, there is no guarantee it is in the Uri to begin with.

```
public static long getId(Uri uri) {
    String path = uri.getPath();
    if ("com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
        int iActual = path.indexOf("ACTUAL");
        if (iActual > -1) {
            String subPath = path.substring(0, iActual - 1);
            uri = Uri.parse(subPath);
        }
    }
    return ContentUris.parseId(uri);
}
```

Usage to get thumb (which can be null):

```
@Nullable
public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Context context, Uri videoUri) {
    long id = getId(videoUri);
    return MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
            id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
}
```

Comment: did you try to get all the data associated with that `videoUri` ? see `MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns` for all the columns you can access

Comment: it seems that not all columns from `MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns` are supported: i couldn't find a way for getting `BaseColumns#_COUNT` field and its documentation is, hmmm, non-existing...

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I did try a query first to get the id. it returned nothing, so I enumerated all the videos and that's actually how I discovered that the id was in the uri already.

Comment: for a quick preview call: `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(MediaStore.Video.query(getContentResolver(), videoUri, null));`

Comment: @pskink I'll give it another go, but as far as I remember that was a query I tried that returned no rows.

Comment: it should return exactly one row: the row describing your video, check it out, note **_id** column

Answer (score 0):

[@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700765/video-picking-is-returning-an-unusual-content-uri-which-fails-to-provide-id-suit?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment53275589_32702346) comment was right, you can get info using a cursor.
Using the [`dumpCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor)) function you can see the available info in the log:

```
Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@461ff77
0 {
    _id=47        
    _display_name=ddmsrec.mp4
    _size=4324395
    mime_type=video/mp4
    _data=/storage/emulated/0/ddmsrec.mp4
    orientation=0
    datetaken=1481123284000
    latitude=null
    longitude=null
    special_type_id=null
}
```

That cursor is the info for this URI, so you can see that the `_id` column is the right value:

```
URI content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F47/ORIGINAL/NONE/864252053
```