# Getting path from Uri from Google Photos app

Tags: android, uri

I have an app which allows to select photos with an external app. Then I take the path of the photo from the uri and use it for internal actions.

When user selects a photo with Google Photo, if the picture is locally stored then the next code works perfectly. But if the picture is in the cloud the result of *cursor.getString(index)* is null.

I've search for some info, but not sure about the solution

```
final String[] projection = { "_data" };
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
    return cursor.getString(index);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527045/choosing-photo-using-new-google-photos-app-is-broken

Comment: @user2765258 I saw that post. But is not a good solution. Even the user said that accepted it because solve the problem but wasn't the complete solution he implemented. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally and according to @CommonsWare answer and the previous post about this issue I solved getting the InputStream from the uri, coping into a new temporal file and passing the path to the function I need to use.

Here is the simplified code:

```
public String getImagePathFromInputStreamUri(Uri uri) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String filePath = null;

    if (uri.getAuthority() != null) {
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); // context needed
            File photoFile = createTemporalFileFrom(inputStream);

            filePath = photoFile.getPath();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // log
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log
        }finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return filePath;
}

private File createTemporalFileFrom(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    File targetFile = null;

    if (inputStream != null) {
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

        targetFile = createTemporalFile();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        outputStream.flush();

        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return targetFile;
}

private File createTemporalFile() {
    return new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "tempFile.jpg"); // context needed
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this help me get rid of 1 P0 :D

Answer (score 4):

> When user selects a photo with Google Photo, if the picture is locally stored then the next code works perfectly.

Not necessarily. There is no requirement for that `Uri` to respond with a `_data` column to a `query()`. There is no requirement for the value it returns to be useful to you (e.g., a file on internal storage or removable storage that you cannot access).

If you need the photo loaded into an `ImageView`, pass the `Uri` to [an image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as Picasso.

If you need the bytes of the photo, use `openInputStream()` with `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Please open and read from the `InputStream` on a background thread.

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that I need the real path due to internal requirements. I'm not going to show or manipulate the image, just pass the path to a backend service that it's already implemented.

Comment: @adalPaRi: There is no "real path". If you need a file, you are welcome to make a copy of the photo, by using the `InputStream` from `openInputStream()` with a `FileOutputStream` to some file that you control.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am having a problem with Google Photos here. I was using Picasso to load the URI into images, and passing the URI between my activities but after some searching I discovered it seems the URI becomes invalid as soon as I leave the `onActivityResult` where I retrieve the intent from Gallery/Camera `ACTION_PICK` Intent chooser. What do you suggest? Any links for recommendation?

Comment: @rgoncalv: You need to use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` whenever passing a `Uri` between components, including your own components. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Comment: I tried this (read your blog post): When coming from Activity A back to Activity B, I add `picIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` before `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, savedPicIntent)`, in a method inside Activity A. I can access the picture perfectly in Activity B (I see the picture in a small frame in Activity B and can go to another Activity C to see the pic on full screen, all as expected), but when sending the pic to the server (using Firebase), in Activity B, the crash happens on this line: ` .putFile(chosenImageUri!!, metadata)`

Comment: @CommonsWare, Here it is the full Firebase method: `val metadata = StorageMetadata.Builder().setContentType("image/jpeg").build()

                            Log.d("TAG", "BEFORE CRASH")   
                                val uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
                .child("requests_images")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                .putFile(chosenImageUri!!, metadata`

Comment: @rgoncalv: I have not tried the `setResult()` approach and so I don't know what the rules are there.  Beyond that, I suggest perhaps asking a separate Stack Overflow question, with your code and the full Java stack trace as part of a [mcve].