# Selecting video from Google Photos provider doesn't give mimetype information

Tags: android, mime-types, google-photos, google-photos-api

I've created a sample [here](https://github.com/ShivamPokhriyal/BuggyGooglePhotos) to reproduce this issue. 
I'm running this project on an emulator with API level 29 and selecting a video from google photos provider. 
**But I cannot figure out how to get the mimeType of the selected file.** 
I've used ContentResolver's getType method which returns null and also ContentResolver query method which somehow throws an IllegalArgumentException to me. I've attached a screenshot for the same. 
[image]

Note: Everything works fine if I select the same file by navigating through the directories, but when I use the google photos provider, it fails.

This is my code::

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_VIDEO_FETCH) {
            Uri selectedFileURI = intent.getData();
            String type = this.getContentResolver().getType(selectedFileURI);

            if (type == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) {
                // This shouldn't happen right?
                // Since https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info
                // mentions a FileProvider determines the file's MIME type from its filename extension. I've to add this block
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFileURI, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID);
                        type = cursor.getString(colIndex);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.d("Check Type :: ", type + "");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Type:: ", type + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I start an intent::

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(i, IMAGE_VIDEO_FETCH);
```

**Can anyone help me out with the correct way to figure out the mimetype of the selected file?** 
PS: I've tried ContentResolver.getType, MimeTypeMap and ContentResolver.query. None of them works.

Comment: Can you provide an example URI?

Comment: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F25/ORIGINAL/NONE/643532680

Comment: I tried your same code, picked a video from "Google Photos" and I am getting the mime type as "video/mp4". Did you confirm that the video is corrupted or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasted couple of days trying to figure out where the problem exists. Unfortunately it turned out to be a bug in google photos version 4.17 which seems to be fixed in version 4.32

Here is the linked google issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149416521

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using to get MimeType:
Unfortunately, it's in Kotlin but let try to use Kotlin, much better.

```
 @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
fun getMimeType(uri: Uri): String {
    val mimeType: String
    mimeType = if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) {
       // Replace MyApplication.getInstance() by your context
        val cr = MyApplication.getInstance().contentResolver
        cr.getType(uri).toString()
    } else {
        val fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(
            uri
                .toString()
        )
        MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            fileExtension.toLowerCase()
        ).toString()
    }
    return mimeType
}
```

I hope this help!

Comment: Hey, Did you check the last part of the question where I mentioned that content resolver getType is not working. And Photos porvider gives ContentSceheme only.