# How can I get image from URI returned from Android photos app?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-photos

I was using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805966/download-image-from-new-google-plus-photos-application) as a reference for how to get the image from a URI with an embedded URL, which was being returned from the Photos app starting a while back. Now, I've noticed that these URIs no longer contain this URL and rather contain some kind of key. I don't know what to do to get this image now. The URI I'm getting back looks like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediaKey:/*long-key*/ACTUAL
```

How are we meant to use this to display a bitmap that a user selected from the Photos app?

Comment: You could use `BitmapFactory` to read in the stream, per yuku's suggestion. Or, most decent image-loading libraries for Android (Picasso, Universal Image Loader, etc.) will be able to handle this `Uri`. Those libraries will handle things like loading the image on a background thread for you, saving you the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Read from the URI using

```
getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
```